# Increasing LED Headlamp Brightness on Vehicle

Tags: led, automotive

The OEM LED headlamps on my vehicle could definitely be brighter. I have a very limited experience in naval electrical engineering so I know the basics. If my goal is to increase brightness of the LED, I would need to increase the current by either reducing the voltage drop or reducing resistance in the circuit.

My first thought is to use a relay connected with the battery so there is a much smaller voltage drop going to the headlamp harness. The worry here is that I could fry the LED chip or put too much load on the resistors/various hardware in the circuit or at the very least piss off the ECU. Opening my headlamp assemblies to access the LED chips/circuit boards is another thought I had - figured I could just change out the resistors, but I would like to avoid doing this if it's not necessary. This is a SPA (Scalable Product Architecture) platform Volvo (MY18+) so the computer operates and maintains just about every aspect of the vehicle.

Increasing the output of my headlamps seems straightforward *in theory* but I am not entirely sure it would be achievable. Any input?

Comment: LED headlights don't use a simple series resistor to limit the current.  [Have a look at this application note from Analog Devices.](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/one-led-driver-is-all-you-need-for-automotive-led-headlight-clusters.html)

Comment: @JRE Interesting read. So I guess what I'm trying to do is not really possible as an average consumer since it is the LED drivers that ultimately set the brightness of the various lighting components and the signals are all controlled by the vehicle's computer. Attempting to manipulate these devices would require Volvo engineering-specific coding. Bummer. I appreciate your input, nonetheless.

Comment: If you intend to pump more current through a LED in an effort to increase brightness, it will likely overheat. In a cooled environment, this might be possible. LED temperature usually sets an upper limit to brightness.

Comment: In some countries you will loose the street permission of your vehicle when you manipulate the LED headlamps. If you increase LED current to much, you will overheat and destroy the LED. Cooling of the LED should not only be sufficient at a cold day in winter but also at a hot day in summer under bright sunlight from a clear sky.

Comment: If they look dim they might be failing. Consider a replacement

Comment: If you want more brightness, it might be better to add auxiliary headlamps designed for your vehicle. https://www.volvopartswebstore.com/products/Volvo/Spot-lights--auxiliary-lights--installation-kit/1252514/30772053-2.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure headlamp brightness is legally restricted (and if it isn't, it should be--I'm fed up with getting blinded by people driving behind me!), and messing with it might render your vehicle no longer street legal.

Answer (score 2):

No. To increase LED brightness, you must increase *cooling / heat-sinking / heat removal*.

Once you've done that, you can think about increasing current.

Now, LEDs are not light bulbs. They are complex semiconductors.  Your ham-handed ideas of how to brighten them are not going to work.  LEDs are highly non-linear, which means small changes in voltage result in large changes in current.  The only way to drive high performance LEDs is with an electronic *constant-current* driver, which regulates current to spec.

To brighten an LED, you would increase the regulated current.